# Sum elements in list under condition(python)

Tags: python, list, sum

```
sum( int(i.replace(',',''))if re.search('\d',i)!=None for i in list)
```

I would like to sum all elements in a list. The problems is that elements are strings, some of them have numbers in them and i would like convert them into integers and then added them up. That is why I need to check if there are numbers in the string. How can I add a condition to the list in the sum function. Also I want to use the sum function I dont want to just iterate through the list and then add to a variable.

Comment: Can you give example in-/output?

Comment: List comprehension with a function built to filter and modify to your requirements seems the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I add a condition to the list in the sum function.

You're nearly there, except that the `if` comes at the end:

```
sum(int(i.replace(',','')) for i in list if re.search(r'\d', i))
```

Having said this, the overall approach is not bullet-proof. It would choke on inputs that mix digits with other characters (e.g. `'a1'`).

Also, the use of the comma as the thousands separator is not universal. [Some locales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) use it to mark the radix point. In those locales, your code would produce incorrect values for numbers with commas in them.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this

```
def safeIntToSum(x):
    try: return int(x.replace(",",""))
    except: return 0

print sum([safeIntToSum(x) for x in list])
```

Comment: I think it's slightly faster if you don't turn it into a list first. eg. `sum(safeIntoSum(x) for x in list)`